# OutOfMemoryError in android while change in orientation?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android.i am loading data from json. While on orientation change destroy and recreate the activity so the json loading everytime orientation changing..

I am getting the following error:

```
{
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
                                                                         at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
                                                                         at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:362)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:385)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:430)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:103)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:385)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
                                                                         at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
                                                                         at com.ProjectName.activities.MainActivity.get_Project_Json(MainActivity.java:238)
                                                                         at com.ProjectName.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                         at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                         at           dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       }
```

especially in JellyBean and KitKat (Device:3.2 to 4.0inches)

{

```
    public void get_Json_Assets() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


 BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new                   InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Somejson.json")));
        String temp;
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(temp);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
           }
       }
        all_Point_Json = sb.toString();
    }
}
{`public void get_Project_Json() {
    get_Json_Assets();
    try {
        JSONObject point_Json= new JSONObject(all_Point_Json);
        JSONArray point_Chapter =point_Json.getJSONArray("chapter");

        for (int i = 0; i < point_Chapter.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> mPoint_Details = new HashMap<>();
            mPoint_Details.put("mPoint", (String) point_Chapter.get(i));
            mPoint_Details.put("mPoint_No", String.valueOf(i + 1));
           All_Point.add(mPoint_Details);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.fillInStackTrace();
    }

}`}
```

Comment: you should post the code also.

Comment: and perhaps try to describe the contents of this json file? if it's a massive file, this is what could be causing the oom error

Comment: My psychic powers are low today, can you post the code that is actually causing this?

Comment: i posted the error showing code

Comment: something doesn't add up - your stack trace clearly shows you trying to create a JSONObject, but the code has no indication of this. Also the method names in the stack trace in the code sample don't match, unless you edit it?

Comment: Just google "stackoverflow android reset on orientation" and you'll see there are like 20 questions asking for the same. Have you read any of them?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is very messy. You should clean it up. Moreover, I don't know in which part of Activity life cycle are you calling this code. I suppose, you're doing it in `onResume()` or `onCreate()` method. Probably this `*.json` file contains a lot of data and you are allocating memory for it. During screen rotation, you're doing it again, after next rotation, memory is allocated again and so on. You should clean memory in `onPause()` method or load this data in a different way (e.g. in the Service and then pass it to Activity). In addition, you should avoid loading large files at once. You can consider loading parts of that file successively and for sure load this data in a separate thread (e.g. with AsyncTask or RxJava if you're familiar with it), because it's non-deterministic and probably a long operation.

Comment: Thanks for response.How to clean memory in android.I did'nt undestand what you mean in clearing memory?

Comment: I meant you can clear stringBuilder as follows: `stringBuilderObj.setLength(0)`, but I'm not sure if it will help because I don't know the whole context. It's just a hint.

Comment: I tried the above hint its also crashing. i did AsyncTask it also crashing.

Comment: Then probably application does not have enough memory to allocate this data into StringBuilder. Try different approach. Maybe streaming JSON as described here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/ or split this data into smaller pieces and don't write everything to the single object at once.